# Unable to open serial port GPIO pins

Tags: raspbian, serial, uart

I'm trying to connect a barcode reader on the UART of the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi 3B+.
I've installed minicom to read the serialport and have allready added the user pi to the groups tty and dialout. I try to communicate to the barcode reader using the following command:

```
minicom -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyS0
```

The output is:

```
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied
```

When adding sudo to the command, I can access the barcode reader, but the output doesn't seem right. When scanning the barcode 604797026269, I get the following output:
[image: Minicom output]
As you can see there is a lot of unknown characters and newlines which shouldn't be here. I'm sure the baud rate is right.

I also tried running the following command before starting minicom:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0
```

Minicom can start now and read the barcode reader for a few minutes, before denying the access again. When scanning a barcode I get the same output as shown above.

I've also tried to connect the barcode reader to a USB port using a TTL-to-USB converter, which works fine.

Please let me know if you got some ideas to fix this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't change permissions on device files, here `/dev/serial0`. This may have unwanted side effects and may confuse the user and group management. User pi should be member of group **dialout**. Check with `groups`.

Comment: @Ingo, thanks for your reply. I'm sorry, I meant /dev/ttyS0 instead of /dev/serial0. User pi is member of the group dialout, so that shouldn't be the problem.